# rpivottable does not work with login module

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, rpivottable

Im trying to use the package `rpivottable` in my app but unfortunally it seems there is a bug. 
First a short introduction in the problem and my app:
The app uses an login interface for authentification. If the user input was valid the ui changes from login to dashboard view. One part of the dashboar is the pivottable. Up to here everythinkg works fine but if I click on the logout button and login again, the pivottable does not show up anymore. I'm trying to fix that issue since days. First I thought that my code is not working  properly but if I replace the pivottable with any other reactive output everthing is working fine. Only when I include the pivottable in the server all reactive outputs are no longer displayed.
The following code is just a snipped of my app.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?
If not - Is there an other way to generate such a table
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJsc.png)?
Would be very grateful for help!

```r
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(shiny, shinyBS, shinydashboard, shinyjs, dplyr,RMySQL,pool,rpivotTable)

#devtools::install_github(c("ramnathv/htmlwidgets", "smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable"))


mydata <- data.frame(
  product = c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'),
  sold = c(5, 10, 15, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 1),
  date = as.Date(c('2010-01-01','2010-01-01','2010-01-01','2010-01-02','2010-01-02','2010-01-02','2010-01-03','2010-01-03','2010-01-03'))
)

user_data <- data.frame(
  user = c("Andreas", "Sascha", "Tobias"),
  password = c("123","123","123"), 
  permissions = c("admin","admin","admin"),
  name = c("Andreas", "Sascha", "Tobias"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = NULL
)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  # Dashboardheader
  dashboardHeader(uiOutput("header")),

  # Dashboardsidebar
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                   sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", sidebarMenuOutput("sidebar"))),

  # Dashboardbody
  dashboardBody(

    # Turn shinyjs on
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

    uiOutput("body")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  # reactive value to trigger the body, sidebar, header of dashboard depending on the login-state 
  values$login <- FALSE

  # header of login-Module (nothing in it)
  login_header <- function(){
  }

  # header if user is logged in
  auth_header <- function(){
    fluidRow(
      column(12,actionButton("logout_button","Logout",class = "btn-danger", style = "color: white; border-color: #d73925; background: #dd4b39")))
  }

  # Sidebar of login-Module (empty)
  login_sidebar <- function(){
    sidebarMenu()
  }

  # Sidebar if user is logged in 
  admin_sidebar <- function(){

    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home"))
    )
  }

  # Body if user is logged in 
  admin_body <- function(){
    tabItems(
      # Body for "Startseite" menuItem  
      tabItem(tabName = "home",class = "active",
              dateRangeInput('dateRangeInput',
                             label = 'Date',
                             start = as.Date(max(mydata$date))-2, 
                             end = as.Date(max(mydata$date)),
                             min = as.Date(min(mydata$date)),
                             max = as.Date(max(mydata$date)),
                             format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                             language = "de"),

              fluidRow(
                tabBox(width = 8,
                       tabPanel("Tabelle", rpivotTableOutput("pivotTable",width = "100%", height = "100%"))
                )
              )
      )
    )
  }

  # Body of login-Module
  login_body <- function(){
    div(id = "panel", style = "width: 500px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;",
        wellPanel(
          tags$h2("LogIn", class = "text-center", style = "padding-top: 0;"),

          textInput("user_name", shiny::tagList(shiny::icon("user"), "Username")),

          passwordInput("password", shiny::tagList(shiny::icon("unlock-alt"), "Password")),

          div(
            style = "text-align: center;",
            actionButton("login_button","LogIn"))
        ),

        shinyjs::hidden(
          div(id = "error",
              tags$p("Wrong Password or Username",
                     style = "color: red; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 5px;", class = "text-center"))
        )
    )
  }


  observeEvent(input$login_button,{
    username_input = input$user_name
    pw_input = input$password

    # get pw of user_name stored in user_data
    pw <- user_data%>%
      filter(user==username_input)%>%
      select(password)%>%
      as.character()

    # if input pw matches pw stored in db set login to true
    if(pw_input==pw){
      values$login <- TRUE
    }
    # else show error
    else{
      shinyjs::toggle(id = "error", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
      shinyjs::delay(5000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "error", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
    }
  })


  observeEvent(values$login,{
    # if login-data was valid show dashboard
    if(values$login){
      output$header <- renderUI(auth_header())
      output$body <- renderUI(admin_body())
      output$sidebar <- renderMenu(admin_sidebar())
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    }
    # else show login module
    else{
      output$body <- renderUI(login_body())
      output$header <- renderUI(login_header())
      output$sidebar <- renderMenu(login_sidebar())
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    }
  })

  # set login to false if user clicks on logout -> go back to login module (see obsereEvent(values$login))
  observeEvent(input$logout_button,{
    values$login <- FALSE
  })

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  #     Pivot Tabelle
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  output$pivotTable <- renderRpivotTable({

  pivot_data <-mydata%>%
      filter(date >= input$dateRangeInput[1] & date <= input$dateRangeInput[2])%>%
      select(product,sold,date)

    rpivotTable(
      data = pivot_data, rows = "product",cols="date", vals = "sold",
      aggregatorName = "Sum", rendererName = "Table",
      subtotals = FALSE)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)
library(rpivotTable)
library(readxl)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(rvest)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use saveWidget function


gm= tags$h3(strong("Good Morning",style="color:#116bac"))
ga= tags$h3(strong("Good Afternoon",style="color:#116bac"))
ge= tags$h3(strong("Good Evening",style="color:#116bac"))

#===========
## FUNCTIONS
#===========
## SIMPLE GREETING
good_time <- function(){

  ## LOAD PACKAGE
  require(lubridate, quietly = T)

  ## ISOLATE currHour
  currhour = hour(now())

  ## RUN LOGIC
  if(currhour < 12){
    return(gm)
  } 
  else if(currhour >= 12 & currhour < 17){
    return(ga)
  }
  else if( currhour >= 17){
    return(ge)  
  }
}



## STARTING LOGGED VALUE; LET'S CHANGE THAT!
Logged = FALSE;


#====
# UI
#====
## make login screen
ui1 <- function(){

  tagList(tags$style(HTML('body {font-family:"Verdana",Georgia,Serif; background-color:#116bac}')),
          div(id="container",align="center",
              div(id = "login",
                  # make login panel
                  wellPanel(id="well",style = "overflow-y: ;width:100%;height:100%",
                            br(),
                            HTML(paste0('
                                        <h2>
                                        Hello, ', good_time(),
                                        '</h2>',
                                        '<h3>
                                        <br>You are in Admin page.</br>
                                        </h3>')
                            ),
                            br(),
                            br(),
                            tags$div(textInput("userName", "Username",width = "100%"),align="left"),
                            br(),
                            tags$div(passwordInput("passwd", "Password",width = "100%"),align="left"),
                            br(),
                            # button
                            tags$div(actionButton("Login", "Log in"),align="center"),
                            # login error message
                            tags$div(uiOutput("message"),align="center")
                            )

                  )
          ),
          # css for container
          tags$style(type = "text/css", 
                     "#container{
                     display: flex;
                     justify-content: center;
                     margin-top: 150px;
}"),
        # css for login well panel
        tags$style(type="text/css", "
                   #login,{
                   font-size:14px; 
                   width: 360px;}"),
        # well panel
        tags$style(type="text/css",
                   "#well{
                   padding: 50px;
                   background: white;
                   border: 1px;
                   box-shadow: ;}"),
        # welcome text css
        tags$style(type = 'text/css',
                   "h2, h3{
                   color: #525252;}"),
        # input fields
        tags$style(type="text/css",
                   "#userName, #passwd{
                   box-shadow: none;
                   outline:none;
                   border: none;
                   padding-left: 0;
                   border-bottom: 2px solid #116bac;
                   border-radius: 0;
                   }
                   #userName:focus, #passwd:focus{
                   box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px lightgray;
                   }"),
        # button css
        tags$style(type='text/css',
                   "#Login{
                   outline: none;
                   margin-left: 0px;
                   width: 100px;
                   font-size: 12pt;
                   background: transparent;
                   border: 2px solid #116bac;
                   color: #116bac;
                   border-radius: 10px;
                   transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
                   }
                   #Login:hover{
                   background: #116bac;
                   color: white;}"),
        # error box - fadeOut animation
        tags$style(type="text/css",
                   "@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
                   from {
                   opacity: 1;
                   }
                   to {
                   opacity: 0;
                   }
                   }
                   @keyframes fadeOut {
                   from {
                   opacity: 1;
                   }
                   to {
                   opacity: 0;
                   }
                   }"),
        tags$style(type="text/css",
                   "#error-box{
                   margin-top: 20px;
                   margin-left: 0px;
                   padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
                   text-align: center;
                   width: 325px;
                   color: white;
                   background: #ef3b2c;
                   border: 1px solid #ef3b2c;
                   border-radius: 5px;
                   -webkit-animation: fadeOut;
                   animation: fadeOut;
                   opacity: 0;
                   animation-duration: 15s;}")
        )
  }

#=========
# PRINT UI
#=========
ui = (uiOutput("page"))

#========
# SERVER
#========

server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2)
  users <- data.frame(User=c("summary"),Password=c("statistics"))
  ## BEGIN BUILD LOG IN SCREEN
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  ## ERROR CHECKING
  observeEvent(input$Login,{

    ## output error message
    output$message <- renderUI({
      if(!is.null(input$Login)){
        my_username <- length(users$User[grep(pattern = input$userName, x = users$User)])
        my_password <- length(users$User[grep(pattern = input$passwd, x = users$Password)])
        if(input$Login > 0){
          if(my_username < 1 ||  my_password < 1){
            HTML("<div id='error-box'>
                 Sorry, that's not the right username or password. Please, 
                 try again. If you continue to have problems,
                 <a href='http://seaportai.com/contact-us/'>
                 <u>Contact Us..</u></a>
                 </div>")
          }
          }
          }
          })

    ## CHECK INPUT
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(users$User == Username)
          Id.password <- which(users$Password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username %in% Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
          })

  ## Make UI
  observe({
    # What to do when logged = F
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }

    # Render UI when logged = T
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      ## get the current user's authorization level 
      user_log <- toupper(input$userName)

      # if admin ("input.SELECT == 1 || input.FED == 2" )
      if(user_log == "SUMMARY" ){
        output$page <- renderUI({
          ###################################################### ADMIN UI PAGE ###################################################################################################################
          fluidPage(


            theme = shinytheme("simplex"),
            tagList(
              useShinyjs(),
            tags$style(HTML("


                            .navbar  {
                            background-color:white; }

                            .navbar .navbar-nav {float: left; 
                            margin-top: 32px;
                            color: #; 
                            font-size: 20px; 
                            background-color: #; }

                            .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-static-top{ 
                            color: #; 
                            font-size: 23px; 
                            background-color: # ;}

                            .navbar .navbar-header {
                            float: left;

                            background-color: # ;}

                            .navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #054b94; 
                            font-size: 28px; 
                            margin-bottom:32px;
                            background-color: # ;} 

                            ")),


            tags$head(HTML("<title>Statistics</title> <link rel='icon' type='image/gif/png' href='log.png'>")),

            navbarPage(id="tabs",

            title = tags$div(img(src="","Statistics", style="color:white;font-weight:200%;margin-top: -5px;margin-left: 30px;", height = 60)),position = "fixed-top",
            selected = tags$div(bsButton("dummy0",strong("Upload"),style = "danger",size="small"),style="color:white;margin-top: -22px;font-weight:100%;",align="center"),inverse = F,

            tabPanel(title = tags$div(bsButton("dummy0",strong("Upload"),style = "danger",size="small"),style="color:white;margin-top: -22px;font-weight:100%;",align="center"),

                     fluidPage(

                       tags$style(" #modal1 .modal-header {background-color:#; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px}
                                  #modal1 .modal-dialog { width: 1800px;}
                                  #modal1 .modal-content  {background-color:#;}"), 

                       tags$style(type="text/css",
                                  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                       ),
                       tags$head(tags$style("#pppp{color:black; font-size:35px; font-style:italic; text-align=center;
                                            overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 300px; background: ghostwhite;}")),
                       tags$head(tags$style("#roi{color:black; font-size:35px; font-style:italic; text-align=center;
                                            overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 300px; background: ghostwhite;}")),


                       br(),
                       br(),
                       br(),

                       column(6,

                              br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),
                              tags$div(id = 'logo1',img(src="https://dunamath.com/image/gif1.gif",height='100%',width='100%'),align="center")
                       ),

                       br(),
                       br(),

                       column(6,


                              bootstrapPage(

                                            br(),
                                            tags$div(id = 'logo2',img(src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/8a/ca/f88acab7ffd127b4465659500aa0538f.gif",height='40%',width='40%'),align="center"),br(),

                                            tags$div(h4(strong(em("Risk Analytics")),style="color:#2e5cb8;font-size:200%"),align="center"),



                                            br(),
                                              uiOutput('fileupload'),
                                              #uiOutput("bss"),br(),
                                              uiOutput('checkbox'),
                                              uiOutput("button"),
                                              uiOutput("helptext"),
                                            br(),
                                            br(),
                                            bsPopover(id = "dummy000",title = "Note:",content = "XXX",placement = "right"),
                                            bsPopover(id="check",title = "",content = "Note: I accept the SeaportAI Terms & Conditions.. Show the Analyse button",placement = "right"),
                                            tags$div(bsButton("reset", label = "Reset ?", icon =   icon("repeat",lib = "glyphicon"),block = F, style="danger",size = "small"),align="center"),


                                            #tags$h1(actionButton("myuser","Logout",icon=icon("user")),style="text-align:center"),
                                            br(),

                                            tags$div(class = "header", checked = NA,style="text-align:center;color:#929292;font-size:100%",
                                                     tags$tbody("Need Help ?"),
                                                     tags$a(href = "http://seaportai.com/contact-us/", "Contact Us...", target="_blank")
                                            ),tags$div(actionLink("reset2",""),align="center"),
                                            br()
                              )
                       )



                       )),



            tabPanel(value = "mytab2",

              title = tags$div(bsButton("dummy",strong("Summay Statistics"),style = "primary",size="small"),style="color:white;margin-top: -22px;font-weight:100%;",align="center"),
              br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),
              # tags$div(selectInput('select1', "Select One...",choices = c("Table", "Image"),selected = "Image"), align = 'center'),
              uiOutput('download1'),
              # uiOutput('download2'),
              tags$div(rpivotTableOutput("test",width = '100%'),align = 'center')

              ),

            tabPanel(
              title = tags$a(href="javascript:history.go(0)",tags$div(bsButton("ss22",strong("Logout"),style = "success",size="small"),
                                                                      style="color:white;margin-top: -12px;font-weight:100%;",align="center"),style="color:white;margin-top: -32px;")
            )









            )
            )
                  )

          #########################################################################################################################################################################



      })
    }



      # if standard user
      else{
        output$page <- renderUI({


        })
      }
    }
    })



  ####################################################### server #############################################################################################




  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    reset(id = "file")
  })

    output[["fileupload"]] <- renderUI({
      input$reset
      tags$div(fileInput("file",label = tags$h4(strong(em("Upload data..")),style="color:#004264;font-size:160%"),accept=c('.xlsx','.xlx')),align="center")

    })




    output[["checkbox"]] <- renderUI({
      input$reset
      tags$div(checkboxInput("check",tags$a(href = "http://seaportai.com/privacy-policy/", "Terms & Conditions",style="color:green;"),value = TRUE),align="center")

    })

    output[["button"]] <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(input$file)) return()
        tags$div(bsButton("analyse",strong("Lets Go..!"),icon = icon("refresh"),style = "primary",size="medium"),
                 style="color:white;font-weight:100%;",align="center")

    })









  ############################################# Data ###############################################################################  

  data <-reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)) {return(NULL)}
    data <- read_excel(file1$datapath)
    #data=data.frame(readxl::read_excel("ega.xlsx"))
    data=data.frame(data)
    data

  })

  observeEvent(input$analyse, {
    confirmSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      inputId = "confirmation",
      type = "warning",
      title = "Are you sure the data was uploaded ?",
      tags$div(strong(h3("If upload Done then go to the Summary Statistics tab for output..",style="color:red;")),align="center"),
      btn_labels = c("Nope", "Yep"),
      danger_mode = TRUE
    )
  })

  session_store <- reactiveValues()

  pivottab = reactive({

    Pivot = rpivotTable(
      data(),
      onRefresh = 
        htmlwidgets::JS("function(config) { 
                           Shiny.onInputChange('myData', document.getElementById('test').innerHTML); 
                        }")
    )

    Pivot

  })

  observeEvent(input$confirmation, {
    if(input$confirmation==TRUE){

      output$test <- renderRpivotTable({
        pivottab()
      })

    }
  })


  summarydf <- eventReactive(input$myData,{
    input$myData %>% 
      read_html %>% 
      html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
      # Turns out there are two tables in an rpivotTable, we want the second
      .[[2]]

  })


  table1 = reactive({
    summarydf()
  })


  output[['download1']] = renderUI({

    if(dim(table1())[1] != 0){

        downloadButton('downloadData1', 'Download Data...')

    }else{

        downloadButton('downloadData2', 'Download Widget')
        # bsButton("downloadData2", "Download Plot")


    }

  })

  output$downloadData1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("dataset-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(table1(), file)
    })

  output$downloadData2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Summary - Statistics", Sys.Date(), ".png", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      #plot(x = data()$vehicle_claim, y = data()$total_claim_amount)
      pivottab()
      dev.off()
      # saveWidget(pivottab(), file, selfcontained = TRUE)

    })

  # observeEvent(input$downloadData2, {
  #   savedPivot <- "savedPivot.html"
  #   saveWidget(pivottab(),file.path(normalizePath(dirname(savedPivot)),basename(savedPivot)))
  # })










  }) # END SHINYAPP

#======
# RUN
#======
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

#save(app,file = "app.rda")
```